SQL - How to speed up a query execution while using JSON_Value in WHERE clause
So, we have a SQL table named Clients which has the following columns:

UniqueId (nvarchar(200), not null)
Data (nvarchar(max), null) - this one has JSON for each row(aprox. 30k-40k characters)

And we got a request to return to our user, UniqueId using the value from one of the parameters nested in Data JSON field (let's call it Value in this example)
We got something like this:
select UniqueId
from dbo.Clients 
where JSON_VALUE(Data,'$.Parent.Child.ChildOfChild.Value') like 'Value'

But, as expected, table which has 20k+ rows and each row contains JSON in Data(with 30k-40k characters) takes a very long time to execute.
Our question is, is there any way to speed up this kind of query? Given the fact that we can't change the table design.
Thanks in advance!

Please show the full table and index definitions, also sample data and expected results, and please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. These details are essential to be able to answer a performance question.

There is normally no way to speed this up other than creating a computed column on JSON_VALUE(....) and indexing it.

This question is similar to: Optimize JSON query processing in SQL Server 2016. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

By storing data as JSON rather than in relational tables, it was decided to make reading and writing easy at the cost of slow searching, if ever needed. Now you do want to search data by JSON and worry about performance?

And when tagging a request with sql always add a tag for your DBMS, too, please.
